# Why Dagger Factory method does not work as Builder does?

Tags: android, dagger-2

In my Android project and in my `app` module, I have a Login screen. I want to provide its view model via dagger. However, it is always `null` although I clearly defined how to generate it in the module class. This is my code:

```
class AuthViewModel(
        private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
        private val logger: Logger
) {

    ....

}
```

This is the module object.

```
@Module
object AuthModule {

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideLogger(): Logger = getLogger() // It creates a Logger object forsure. I confirm it doesn't return null.

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideViewModel(firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth, logger: Logger) = AuthViewModel(firebaseAuth, logger)

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideFirebaseAuth() = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
}
```

this is the component

```
@FeatureScope
@Component(modules = [AuthModule::class])
interface AuthComponent {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(
                @BindsInstance context: Context
        ): AuthComponent
    }

}
```

This is how I inject it into my activity.

```
class AuthActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var vm: AuthViewModel
    @Inject lateinit var logger: Logger

    companion object {
        private val TAG = AuthActivity::class.java.simpleName

        fun startActivity(ctx: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(ctx, AuthActivity::class.java)
            ctx.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        DaggerAuthComponent.factory()
                .create(this)

        logger.logDebug("test") // <==== Crashes here because logger is null
    }
}
```

Application crashes at the marked line above because logger is `null`. I debugged the app and notices the ViewModel is null, too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the problem exactly but I replaced Factory with Builder and my problem was fixed.

You are welcome to tell me what is the problem in my original code and I will be more than happy to accept your answer.

```
@FeatureScope
@Component(modules = [AuthModule::class])
interface AuthComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): AuthComponent

        @BindsInstance fun activity(context: Context): Builder
    }

    fun inject(activity: AuthActivity)
}
```

Comment: You never actually called `inject(this)` in your original example

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, you know, sometimes I play the role of an idiot very well and it was my masterpiece. I just tested and you are right. I will be more than happy to accept your comment if you turn it in to answer. Thanks.